# Geocoding API usage limits at project level or account level?

Tags: api, google-maps, geocoding

Would someone be kind enough to tell me whether the Google API usage limits specified here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits are calculated set at the project level, or account level please?

I'm using one API key for several maps on our website.  Total calls per day limit is no problem at all.  We're occasionally clocking more than 50 requests per second in peak times though.

If I create a new project, and get a new API key in the same account, will that mean we can hit 50 requests per second on one API key, and 50 requests per second separately on another API key...or are they calculated at the account level?

Many thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

The documentation states the following:

> Most of the Google Maps APIs have a complimentary per-day quota that can be set in the Google API Console. The daily default and maximum query limits vary by API. You can increase the complimentary daily limits by enabling billing, or purchasing a Google Maps APIs Premium Plan license. **Quota limits are enforced on a unique project basis**, and you may not take any action to circumvent quota limits. For example, you may not create multiple projects to compound and exceed quota limits.

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage-limits

So, as you can see the usage quota is calculated on the per project basis.   If you use two API keys from different projects each one will have its own usage limits. Also you cannot create unlimited number of project for one account. As far as I know you can create approximately 16 projects within one account.

I hope this clarifies your doubt.

Answer (score -1):

The usage limits are calculated at the account level, not the project or key level.  They do this to prevent people from just creating unlimited projects to get around the acceptable usage limits that they are providing.

Comment: I disagree with this answer, because documentation clearly says that usage limit is applied on per project basis.

Comment: It's good to have different perspectives. In this case we might be saying similar things from a different stance. I'm pointing  out that there is a cap and it is applied to the account and distributed among the projects but that there is also a cap on the number of projects in order to prevent abuse. Thanks for bringing your take on it as well @xomena